# Replace the placeholder in the String with actual value using jq

Tags: json, string-matching, jq

It is not working.  How to check the part of the String (not the whole String)?

### test.json

```
{
 "url": "https://<part1>.test/hai/<part1>"
}



jq --arg input "$arg" \
   'if .url == "<part1>"
     then . + {"url" : ("https://" + $input + ".test/hai/" + $input)  }
       else . end' test.json  > test123.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test.json, the value of .url is `"https://<part1>.test/hai/<part1>"` so evidently you don't want to check that its value is `"<part1>"`.

Perhaps you meant to test the condition: `.url | contains("<part1>")` or maybe `.url | endswith("<part1>")` -- the problem description is unclear.

If your jq has support for regular expressions, you could use `test/1`, e.g.

```
.url | test("//<part1>.*<part1>$")
```

Another possibility would be to use `gsub`.

Comment: This is not working and throwing an error.      jq --arg input "$arg" \
   'if .url | contains( "<part1>")
     then . + {"url" : ("https://" + $input + ".test/hai/" + $input)  }
       else . end' test.json  > test123.json